# Android dynamic TableRow setLayoutParams not working

Tags: android, android-tablelayout, tablerow

I have a TableLayout in my xml and I am able to dynamically add TableRow with TextViews inside my TableLayout, But the problem is, the width and height are not being set to what I have set.

```
                    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
                    tr.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 0);

                    TextView labelTV = new TextView(this);
                    labelTV.setText(strWork);
                    labelTV.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#D69E29"));
                    labelTV.setTextSize(16);
                    labelTV.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                            130,
                            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    tr.addView(labelTV);

                    mTable.addView(tr);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to this

```
TableRow.LayoutParams prms = new TableRow.LayoutParams(130,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
tr.addView(labelTV,prms);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: its the width wrong right? maybe your TableLayout has less width than that?

Comment: it's working now! the parameter is not in dp? I have to key in a larger value to see the effect.